# How to detect visitor country using simple Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, squarespace

This code is not working on squarespace, can someone identify whats wrong with this code. However, its working on jsfiddle.

```
<script src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery.getScript('http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp', function() 
    {
        var country = geoplugin_countryName();
        alert(country);
        var code = geoplugin_countryCode();
        alert(code);
        console.log("Your location is: " + country + ", " + zone + ", " + district);
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the jquery error you are getting on console ?

Comment: No there is no error, no alert after page load.

Comment: I have added code in the answer, try that out. It was working for me and I have added certain things too. Also, check console for the result I have removed the alert thing.

Comment: I run your code still no alert pops up. If I create simple alert message it runs so jquery is working but this code is not working on squarespace. Instead of alert is there a way to display the country and message on-site.

Comment: See the console I have removed the alert

Comment: Yes you can add it as a text to the webpage, like `document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = "<Required String here>"`

Comment: You also need to add in HTML as, `<div id="target"></div>`

Comment: Also I have added alert to the code you can check it now

Comment: The page at 'https://www.example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. I get this error in console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220703/discussion-between-nikhil-singh-and-emma-expat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added the code for region and city which was missing, try this it works now,

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery.getScript('http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp', function() 
    {
        const country = geoplugin_countryName();
        const countryCode = geoplugin_countryCode();
        const city = geoplugin_city();
        const region = geoplugin_region();
        console.log(`Your location is: ${city}, ${region}, ${country}, ${countryCode}`);
        alert(`Your location is: ${city}, ${region}, ${country}, ${countryCode}`)
    });
});
```

Update:-

As the above plugin was hosted over HTTP and was giving error, this is the alternate solution to it,

```js
fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = `Your location is: ${res.city}, ${res.region}, ${res.country}`;
  })
  .catch((data, status) => {
    console.log('Request failed');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables "zone" and "district" are not defined, remove them and it will work, use this:

```
<script src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        jQuery.getScript('http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp', function () {
            var country = geoplugin_countryName();
            alert(country);
            var code = geoplugin_countryCode();
            alert(code);
            console.log("Your location is: " + country);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the undefined variables, still it's not working in Squarespace Code injection field